Output characters to Word document with different formatting for each character
ChatGPT and I are writing a program to manipulate a Word document that will contain songs and lyrics written in a new music notation system as described here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSkx76Kjfmw The width of each letter (note) is changed using the font scaling capability of Word and indicates how long the note is played for:

The module we are currently working on will vertially align the notes with the lyrics syllables and output them with increased or decreased spacing between them, as per the image above. (It will be the only music notation program that automatically detects syllables without needing the user to manually hyphenate multi-syllable words).
The notes are in Courier New font so the characters are all the same width (before scaling). Every character, including the spaces between the notes, has unique font formatting (Font name, Size, Bold and Scaling)
Neither I nor ChatGPT can get the formatting right. Our code reads in each character and stores it along with the Font attributes. After determining how many spaces are required  the characters have to be written back using the same attributes as they had before. The spaces are scaled down to 30% to allow finer gap adjustment.
This is the code we have come up with so far to output one line of notes after deleting the existing line but it does not work. It writes the characters to the start of the next line instead of the current line and does not apply the unique font attributes to each character.
Sub InsertNotesIntoDocument(notesLine As NotesLineClass)
    Dim lineNumber As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim noteClass As noteClass
    Dim noteSubClass As noteSubClass
    
    ' Determine the line number to insert the notes into
    lineNumber = notesLine.lineNumber

    ' Set the range to the start of the specified line within the selection
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(lineNumber).Range
    rng.End = rng.End - 1 ' Exclude paragraph mark at the end of the line

    ' Clear the existing content of the line (except the paragraph mark)
    rng.Text = vbNullString
    
    ' Iterate through each NoteClass object in the collection
    For Each noteClass In notesLine.Notes
        ' Set font properties for the entire note
        With rng.Font
            .Name = noteClass.FontName
            .Size = noteClass.FontSize
        End With
        
        ' Iterate through each SubNoteClass object in the SubNotes collection
        For Each noteSubClass In noteClass.SubNotes
            ' Insert a new range for each character insertion
            Dim charRng As Range
            Set charRng = rng.Duplicate
            
            ' Apply character-specific properties
            With charRng.Font
                .Bold = noteSubClass.Bold
                .Scaling = noteSubClass.Scaling
            End With
            
            ' Insert the character into the document
            charRng.Text = noteSubClass.NoteChar
            
            ' Move the original range to the end of the inserted character
            rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Next noteSubClass
        
        ' Insert spaces scaled to 30% between notes if needed
        For i = 1 To noteClass.PaddingBytes
            rng.Text = " " ' Insert a space directly using the main range
            rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd ' Move past the space
        Next i
    Next noteClass
End Sub



I solved it. ChatGPT was trying to set the font attributes in the wrong place and at the wrong stage.
Sub InsertNotesIntoDocument(notesLine As NotesLineClass)
    Dim lineNumber As Integer
    Dim FontSize As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim noteClass As noteClass
    Dim noteSubClass As noteSubClass
    Dim rng, charRng As Range
   
    lineNumber = notesLine.lineNumber  ' Line number to insert the notes into
    FontSize = notesLine.FontSize  ' Font size

    ' Set the range to the start of the specified line within the selection
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(lineNumber).Range
    rng.End = rng.End - 1 ' Exclude paragraph mark at the end of the line

    ' Clear the existing content of the line (except the paragraph mark)
    rng.Text = vbNullString
    
    ' Iterate through each NoteClass object in the collection
    For Each noteClass In notesLine.Notes
        
        ' Iterate through each SubNoteClass object in the SubNotes collection
        For Each noteSubClass In noteClass.SubNotes
            ' Insert the character into the document
            rng.Text = noteSubClass.NoteChar
            With rng.Font           ' Set font attributes
                .Name = "Courier New"
                .Size = FontSize
                .Bold = noteSubClass.Bold
                .Scaling = noteSubClass.Scaling
            End With
            
            ' Move the original range to the end of the inserted character
            rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
       Next noteSubClass
        
        ' Insert spaces scaled to 30% between notes if needed
        For i = 1 To noteClass.PaddingBytes
            rng.Text = " " ' Insert a space
            rng.Font.Scaling = 30
            rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd ' Move past the space
        Next i
    Next noteClass
End Sub

